# prediction step in RNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Assuming I have already trained a recurrent neural network for doing POS tagging, with time step = 2, what is the correct way to do the prediction for a new incoming input?

I have 3 weight matrices: `input->hidden (Wxh)`, `hidden->hidden (Why)`, `hidden->output (Why)`.

If I have to perform the prediction as the feedforward step then what will be my initial input (h) for hidden->hidden connection?

Also, since I am time step as 2, would the prediction on the first time step (first word) even be correct if I use a randomly initialized h?

Where can I read more about the prediction step in RNN?